# How to import function when using tkinter module without ValueError

Tags: python, tkinter, import, anaconda, spyder

I am using tkinter for my GUI and I'm trying to import a simple function from one file (desde.py) to the other (importar.py)

The file from it will be imported the function has just the following:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def sumar():
    s.set( int(e1.get()) + int(e2.get()) )
    e1.set("")
    e2.set("")

e1 = StringVar()
e2 = StringVar()
s = StringVar()

root.mainloop()
```

In the other file (importar.py) where the function sumar() will be imported has two entries, one button and one label (for the answer of the sum) packed, but what is important here is the import statement as I have it:

```
from tkinter import *
from desde import sumar

root = Tk()

sumar()

e1 = StringVar()
e2 = StringVar()
s = StringVar()

#code of entries, button and label

root.mainloop()
```

And when I execute, I get: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

I don't understand why nor what is that. What can I do so this function really works? What would you do in this particular case?

Answer (score 0):

Ola, I think that if you declare 's' as  StringVar you can't use int type to set it.

see below

> importar.py

```
from tkinter import *
from desde import sumar

root = Tk()

print(sumar())

#code of entries, button and label

root.mainloop()
```

> desde.py

```
 from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

e1 = StringVar()
e2 = StringVar()
s = StringVar()

x = IntVar()
y = IntVar()
z = IntVar()


def sumar():

    e1.set(5)
    e2.set(5)

    x.set(5)
    y.set(5)

    s.set(e1.get() + e2.get())
    z.set(x.get() + y.get())



    return s.get(),z.get()



root.mainloop()
```

notice the difference between z and s sum